# Using SCOPE_IDENTITY() in a constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, identity, identity-column

I am aware that using `IDENT_CURRENT` will not always return me the correct identity value (especially true in multi-threaded applications). I wanted to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead.

For example this is my `Employee` table:

```
create table Employee
(
    ID      int identity(1,1),
    Name    varchar(20),
    SystemID int,
    constraint Employee_PK primary key (ID asc)
)
```

I have a statement below:

```
alter table Employee 
  add constraint Employee_D1 default ident_current('Employee') for SystemID
```

which I need to modify to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead.

I tried the below:

```
alter table Employee 
  add constraint Employee_D1 default SCOPE_IDENITITY() for SystemID
```

This did not give any errors. But upon inserting a row, I did not see this column getting updated with the identity value. What am I doing wrong?

Note that the `SystemID` must not be readonly, so computed field isn't an option.

My exercise here is to try eliminating entry of wrong `IDENTITY` value in `SystemID` in case parallel processes try to insert rows.

Comment: The issue is with ident_current is if you're using it to predict the next value, otherwise it should be safe to use as it gives you the last identity value for any session. SCOPE_IDENTITY only works on the current session and I think that's why you don't get a value from it.
But I'm unsure about what benefit you're getting from that constraint?

Comment: Agree with Allan - what is the point of having a column with a default of `SCOPE_IDENTITY`?? If you need a unique value in your table - use a column of type `INT IDENTITY` - but what's the benefit of having a second column with the same value? If you must have something like this - you'll need to use an `ON INSERT` trigger....

Comment: I'm confused - `ID` is _already_ an `IDENTITY` column - are you trying  to ensure that `SystemID` is always equal to `ID`?  Or to an `ID` in some other table?

Comment: Why in the world would you want two columns holding the exact same data in the same table?

Comment: The SystemID will actually have a different value based on some other constraint, and store ID otherwise. The example I gave is just a simplified version that concentrates on just the issue I'm facing, and not on the business rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-read your answer. SystemID isn't an identity column. I don't think you can use SCOPE_IDENITITY() as it hasn't added the row and retrieved the new Identity value at the point it would need the value to save.

What you will need to do is create a trigger After Insert of the row to update the SystemId value. [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Would an `AFTER INSERT` trigger be helpful in updating `SystemID` with the correct identity value in case parallel processes are inserting rows?

Comment: Yes. As long as you use the inserted table in your trigger to get the new ID. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach this problem (apologies for the poor field names, I'm not feeling inventive)

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
   id               int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
 , name             varchar(20)       NOT NULL
 , actual_system_id int                   NULL
 , system_id As Coalesce(actual_system_id, id)
 , CONSTRAINT pk_employees PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
;

INSERT INTO employees (name)
  VALUES ('John')
       , ('Paul')
       , ('George')
       , ('Ringo')
;

SELECT id
     , name
     , system_id
FROM   employees
;

UPDATE employees
SET    actual_system_id = 937
WHERE  name = 'George'
;

SELECT id
     , name
     , system_id
FROM   employees
;
```